# How to create a dynamic Boolean menu

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a menu with Boolean options in Pine script.

I have in my code a dynamic form to clustering data. If I select the number 5, it makes 5 groups.

I want to create a Boolean menu to show only the groups of interest.

My Boolean menu looks like

```
Number_of_groups = 5

for i = 0 to Number_of_groups -1
    input.bool(true, "Group:" + srt.tostring( i ), group="Select group of interest")
```

With this form, I would like the menu show me the Boolean option to each group. And after that I will remove from visualization the groups that's setting false.

It doesn't work. Pine script show me the next message:

> An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected.

Your answer can´t say: "The unique form to create input.bool() is knowing before the max number of groups possible and create all the inputs possibles in the script, one by one". I know it works, but I´m finding a form to make it dynamic, to doesn´t need open the source code if I have groups number greater than expectation.